# Logrotate - can I configure multiple services in one configuration file?

Tags: logrotate

I am planning some infrastructural architecture. It seems as if logrotate configuration files in `/etc/logrotate.d` usually handle exactly one type of log rotation.

My question: Would it be possible to create a file like `/etc/logrotate.d/my_company`, which configures multiple different log rotations for different log files? Is it possible to combine the content of multiple logrotate configuration files into one file?

Example:

```
/var/log/service_1
{
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    daily
    rotate 31
}

/var/log/service_2
{
    daily
    rotate 7
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there should be no problem having multiple definitions in a file. The logrotate.conf just appends the contents of all the logrotate.d/* files into its main logrotate.conf. To illustrate, the config file for apt includes multiple log files in one:

```
/var/log/apt/term.log {
    rotate 12
    monthly
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
}

/var/log/apt/history.log {
    rotate 12
    monthly
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Logrotate configuration works per log file, not per module or service.